# How to properly hide functions without getting 'unused function' warnings

Tags: c, static, warnings

I have the following `.c` files:

difficult_calculations.c

```
#include difficult_calculations.h
#include helper_functions.c    

int do_difficult_calculations() {
    return helper_function();
}
```

helper_functions.c

```
static int helper_function() {
    return 42;
}
```

I declared `helper_function()` as `static` because I want to keep it hidden from the rest of the code. However, I still want to unit test it. In my test file `test.c` I then do

```
#include helper_functions.c

void test_helper_function() {
    // Testing code
}
```

Doing so gives me `unused function` warnings, both in `gcc` and `clang`. I could of course turn those warnings off with `-W-no-unused-function`, **but I wanted to check if there is an alternative, cleaner way of defining the helper functions as `static` without getting these warnings?**

Defining the functions as `static` functions in the `difficult_calculations.c` file is not an option, because I will get `duplicate symbols (do_difficult_calculations())` if I include `difficult_calculations.c` multiple times (e.g. in different totally independent unit testing files).

Comment: [`__attribute__((unused))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bunused_007d-function-attribute-3264) should work in both gcc and clang.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But those functions are not actually unused, so in my opinion that's not really a clean solution.

Comment: They are unused in the context where you are getting the warnings.  This particular warning never has false positives. I presume the issue is that `helper_functions.c` contains several helper functions, only one of which is tested in any given unit test, which is a perfectly sensible design and exactly what `__attribute__((unused))` is meant to be used for.

Comment: That is not true. If I compile the file `helper_functions.c` alone with `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`, I still get the warnings. Merely the functions not being used in that file is enough to yield these warnings.

Comment: ... Well, yes, that's what the warning means: the functions are not used in that translation unit, and because they're `static`, they can't be used by another TU.  I think I don't understand what you actually _want_.

Comment: By your comment, I understand what I do wrong. I should compile only `difficult_calculations.c`, not `helper_functions.c`. Doing so, I don't need to turn off any warning flags or `__attribute__`s. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thought all along you were getting these warnings from your unit test files.